# jQuery: how to find that prevous checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a code that each checking/unchecking the checkbox respectively adds/subtracts a certain amount. Everything works perfectly, but when the first checbox leave "checked" and I press to a second, then the first checbox I "unchecked", but the script didn't subtracts a certain amount. I want to create if, that can match previous checbox and present (it is different), and if it's different will take away a certain amount of this first. This is my if instruction (`lastClicked.find('input[type=checbox]').attr("checked")` doesn't work)

```
if(!((lastClicked.length == $(this).length && lastClicked.length == lastClicked.filter($(this)).length) || lastClicked==="") && lastClicked.find('input[type=checbox]').attr("checked"))
```

And here is code:
https://jsfiddle.net/3p5z6zov/

Comment: If I use prop() instead of attr() and change 'input[type=checbox]' to 'input:checkbox' that it works. It was stupid question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use prop() instead of attr()

►If you're using jQuery 1.6 or later, use prop() instead of attr()

```
lastClicked.find('input[type=checbox]').prop("checked")
```

When you are using [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop()/), the value returned will be Boolean